# object gets passed to action as string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that has a hidden field wich stores a `object`. This object is a RoutesValues (I want to store a reference because when I process the form I want to redirect to a route). The action that processes the form is:

```
public ActionResult Añadir(string userName, string codigoArticulo, string resultAction, string resultController, object resultRouteValues, int cantidad)
{
    processForm(codigoArticulo, cantidad);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        TempData["Error"] = @ErrorStrings.CantidadMayorQue0;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resultAction) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resultController))
        return RedirectToAction(resultAction, resultController, resultRouteValues);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Busqueda", new {Area = ""});
}
```

and my form is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Añadir", "Carrito", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "afegidorCarrito" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="codigoArticulo" value="@Model.CodiArticle" />
        <input type="hidden" name="resultController" value="@Model.Controller" />
        <input type="hidden" name="resultAction" value="@Model.Action" />
        <input type="hidden" name="resultRouteValues" value="@Model.RouteValues" />
        <input type="text" name="cantidad" value="1" class="anadirCantidad" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

the problem I have is that resultRouteValues gets passed as a string instead of an object. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easy way if `RouteValues` is a complex object. You will have to serialize the object into some text representation into this hidden field and then deserialize it back in your controller action. You may take a look at MvcContrib's [Html.Serialize](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx) helper.